# Xamarin.Mac - Issue submitting to Mac App Store

Tags: c#, .net, macos, monomac, xamarin.mac

We are in the process of submitting our app for the Mac App Store. I get the following email from Apple when submitting to the store:

```
Dear developer,

We have discovered one or more issues with your recent delivery for "YourApp". To process your delivery, the following issues must be corrected: 

App sandbox not enabled - The following executables must include the "com.apple.security.app-sandbox" entitlement with a Boolean value of true in the entitlements property list. Refer to the App Sandbox page for more information on sandboxing your app. 

•   YourApp.app/Contents/MacOS/YourApp

Once these issues have been corrected, go to the Version Details page and click "Ready to Upload Binary." Continue through the submission process until the app status is "Waiting for Upload." You can then deliver the corrected binary.
```

Under Project Options->Mac OS X Application, I have:

- Enable Entitlements – checked
- Some iCloud stuff auto-filled out
- Enable App Sandboxing – checked
- Allow outgoing network connections – checked

Under Mac OS X Packaging – I manually selected an App Store distribution certificate as well.

To submit, I’ve been using Build->Archive and submitting from inside XCode. If I “validate” inside XCode, there are no errors.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sent this issue to Xamarin Support, and they figured it out.

They send me a new version of Xamarin to install that fixed the issue.

Should be an update soon if other people have this issue.